# Getting class cast exception when trying to open a file in eclipse programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an eclipse plug-in where in I am trying to open a file on an Editor programmability .

I am doing following as explained in https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically%3F

```
IWorkbenchPage page = ...;
IFile file = ...;
IEditorDescriptor desc = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
    getEditorRegistry().getDefaultEditor(file.getName());
page.openEditor(new FileEditorInput(file), desc.getId());
```

But I am getting following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.IFileEditorInput
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.model.FileInputAdapterFactory.getAdapter(FileInputAdapterFactory.java:31)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.adapter.AdapterFactoryProxy.getAdapter(AdapterFactoryProxy.java:82)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.getAdapter(AdapterManager.java:301)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.PlatformObject.getAdapter(PlatformObject.java:68)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput.getAdapter(FileEditorInput.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.DocumentProviderRegistry.getDocumentProvider(DocumentProviderRegistry.java:311)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.setDocumentProvider(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1441)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.updateDocumentProvider(AbstractTextEditor.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractTextEditor.java:4225)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.doSetInput(StatusTextEditor.java:237)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.doSetInput(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.internalDoSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2590)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSetInput(JavaEditor.java:2563)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.doSetInput(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1392)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3220)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:371)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2156)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2152)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3238)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3265)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.initialize(EditorReference.java:361)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:319)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1306)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4633)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:494)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:458)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3234)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3131)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3126)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3090)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3071)
at edu.sssihl.mca.vishwakarma.views.MetricTable$5.run(MetricTable.java:243)
at edu.sssihl.mca.vishwakarma.views.MetricTable$1.doubleClick(MetricTable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:832)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:829)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleDoubleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1263)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:252)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:311)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1329)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Why is this exception coming. Can any one help me...

Here is the MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Vishwakarma1
Bundle-SymbolicName: Vishwakarma1;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: edu.sssihl.mca.vishwakarma.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: edu.sssihl.mca
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.11.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.10.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/org.swtchart_0.9.0.v20140219.jar,
 lib/org.swtchart.ext_0.9.0.v20140219.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.7.0.I20110519-0100.jar,
 lib/poi-3.13-20150929.jar,
 lib/poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar,
 lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar,
 lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.core.filesystem-1.3.100.jar
Export-Package: edu.sssihl.mca.vishwakarma.datamodel,
 edu.sssihl.mca.vishwakarma.datamodel.metric,
 edu.sssihl.mca.vishwakarma.datamodel.smell
```

Comment: Looks like some sort of problem with classpaths. Where are you getting the FileEditorInput class from? Show us your MANIFEST.MF and the project .classpath file

Comment: I am getting the FileEditorInput by instantiating it `IEditorInput editorInput = new FileEditorInput(ifile);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included a version of the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` jar in the `lib` directory of your plugin and put it in the `Bundle-ClassPath`. This will result in the `FileEditorInput` class being loaded from the wrong jar giving the error you are getting.

Remove the

```
lib/org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.7.0.I20110519-0100.jar
```

and

```
lib/org.eclipse.core.filesystem-1.3.100.jar
```

from your lib and the `Bundle-Classpath`.

Add `org.eclipse.ui.ide` and `org.eclipse.core.filesystem` to the `Require-Bundle` entry.

Never add Eclipse jars to your plugin, always reference them using `Require-Bundle`.